# Compare last value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
distance

0       0.000000
1       0.001956
2       0.001601
3       0.001601
4       0.003379
      ...   
1236    0.150453
1237    0.152232
1238    0.157923
1239    0.159701
1240    0.159879

Name: close, Length: 1241, dtype: float64
```

I want to check if last value in dataframe is > 15 or not.

I tried it the following way:

```
if distance.tail(1) > 15:
   print('bigger > 15')
else:
   print('less < 15')
```

which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), 
a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: use `df.iloc[-1]`

Comment: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`. Your `distance` var is a `pd.Series`, not a `pd.DataFrame`. Else it would have said: `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.tail` returns a Series.

Use `df.iloc`:

```py
if distance.iloc[-1] > 15:
   print('> 15')
else:
   print('<= 15')
```

Comment: I did the same thing....but it looks like they have a Series not a DataFrame...so you don't need .values

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that!

Comment: "`df.tail` returns a Series"? Well, it does, but only because the `df` in question *is* a Series.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of iloc and indexing -1 will work.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 25])
data.columns = ['colname']
data.iloc[-1]['colname']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first it looks like you have a pandas Series not DataFrame. But this is how you would do it...

```
distance.iloc[-1] > 15
```